# JPype won't compile properly when run the code twice

Tags: python, anaconda, jpype

my code:

```
jarLocation = "C:/Users/LahiruGunawardhana/Desktop/New folder/info/infodynamics.jar"
# Start the JVM (add the "-Xmx" option with say 1024M if you get crashes due to not enough memory space)

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea", "-Djava.class.path=" + jarLocation,"-Xmx256m")

teCalcClass = jpype.JPackage("infodynamics.measures.discrete").TransferEntropyCalculatorDiscrete
teCalc = teCalcClass(2,1)
teCalc.initialise()

noOfEdges=0
for i in range(0,N-1):
  for j in range(i+1,N):
   # print(i,"-->",j)
    if(nodes_connectivity(j,i) | nodes_connectivity(i,j)):

     sss = [int(i) for i in SsourceArray]
     ddd = [int(i) for i in DdestArray]
     teCalc.addObservations(sss, ddd)
     e=teCalc.computeAverageLocalOfObservations()

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

I'm getting values only once for this code. when i run this code a second time I'm getting an error saying:

```
_jpype.startup(jvm, tuple(args), True)

OSError: JVM is already started
```

Somehow, when i restart the python console for each step it gives values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **isJVMStarted()** before **startJVM()** so it would be something like:

```
if jpype.isJVMStarted():
    return

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea", "-Djava.class.path=" + jarLocation,"-Xmx256m")
```

So if you run twice and a JVM is running this code will avoid initializing it again

Comment: thank you. how can use option "-Xmx" in my code because i'm getting crashes due to not enough memory when run the code more than once.

Comment: @LahiruGunawardana -Xmx specifies the maximum heap size, so now you have "-Xmx256m". This means that you have a maximum of 256MB. Try to rise the number with "-Xmx512m" (512MB), "-Xmx1024m" (1024MB) or "-Xmx2048m" (2048MB).

Comment: So the code would be: jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea","-Xmx1024m" ,"-Djava.class.path=" + jarLocation)